# Signup form the profile update after creating user auth is not working Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a form for singup that was saving the name of the user including a photoURL, extra. Today for some reason is not working anymore the Name saving, at least when i extract the data with firebase CLI I cannot see it. Please see the code below:

I tried to change the logic, also notice the user is not entering to the second then

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
      <form class="register-form" id="register-form">
        <input type="text" id="displayName" name="displayName" placeholder="name"/>
        <input type="text" id="token" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="token"/>
        <input type="password" id="password"name="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email address"/>
        <button type="button" onclick="registerPasswordUser();">register</button>
        
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };
 
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const auth = firebase.auth();

  function registerPasswordUser(){
    var form = document.getElementById("register-form");

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var displayName = document.getElementById("displayName").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var photoURL = document.getElementById("token").value;

    var user = null;

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function () {
      if (auth && auth.currentUser) {
        user = auth.currentUser;
        console.log('auth', auth);
        console.log('currentUser', auth.currentUser);
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      }
    })
    .then(function () {
      user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: photoURL
      });
      form.reset();
      document.getElementById("email").value = "";
      document.getElementById("displayName").value = "";
      document.getElementById("password").value = "";
      document.getElementById("token").value = "";
      location.reload();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.message,7000);
    });
   
  }
</script>
```

Also not getting any error on the console and the email and the password are being created properly. At least that what I can see in the console. Do you have any idea?

*** UPDATE ***

To update my question, I just realize that this works on IE, where is saving the Name of the user, if I use another browser, just don't simple works, and as mentioned before, don't get any error and save well the email and password.

Answer (score 0):

This code here won't work as expected:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function () {
      if (auth && auth.currentUser) {
        user = auth.currentUser;
        console.log('auth', auth);
        console.log('currentUser', auth.currentUser);
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      }
    })
```

The `auth.currentUser` won't have the user as you expect it to have even if you use an async call. You can either use the value you get in your then function like here:

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Or make the sync everytime the user changes using this kind of code:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```